# Namespace confusion using C++/CLI in Windows Forms Application

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I'm trying to save myself some coding time by taking advantage of `using namespace` in a Windows Forms project. I created a default Windows Forms project using C++/CLI in VS2010. I notice that the default namespaces that are imported are:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

I want to create a `DialogResult`-typed variable, which (conveniently enough!) sits inside the `System::Windows::Forms` namespace. I go into the constructor for the default `Form1` and add the line:

```
DialogResult dr;
```

I get the compiler error `syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dr'`.

However, if I change the line to either:

```
Windows::Forms::DialogResult dr;
```

or

```
System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult dr;
```

then everything works as expected.

I also tried adding

```
using namespace System::Windows;
```

and then

```
Forms::DialogResult dr
```

works too!

What am I missing about how these namespaces are working?! I'd like to avoid having to fully qualify all of the code I'm writing, but I can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong since the namespace I need should already be imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System::Windows::Forms::Form` has a property named `DialogResult`, so inside of a `Form` subclass that property has scope precedence over the type in the global namespace.

I usually work around this with a typedef:

```
typedef System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult DialogResult_t;
```

Then any time you need to use the type, use `DialogResult_t`, and any time you need to access the property, use `DialogResult`.

Note that this issue is not C++/CLI specific – C++ has the same scoping rules and consequently would have the same problem; it's just that the .NET BCL reuses type names as property names quite extensively (where C++ code would avoid that) because *C#* does not have this issue.

Comment: Grr! I should have figured this one out, but great explanation and helpful advice! Thanks a lot!